# Prevent to auto select item from spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

So I create something like this:

```
final BluetoothSocket[] clientSocket = new BluetoothSocket[1];
    devicesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            try {
                BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(devices.get(i).getAddress());
                Method m = remoteDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
                clientSocket[0] = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(remoteDevice, 1);
                Log.i("DATA_FROM_REMOTE_DEVICE", "" + clientSocket[0].getInputStream().read());
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("REMOTE_DEVICE", "No such a method", e);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected to: " + devices.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView<?> adapterView){

        }
    });
```

The problem is if I add between "try catch" block:

```
clientSocket[0].connect();
```

Everything is works fine, except that when I run app and data are loaded to spinner, it automatically start connecting to first found device, that is not what I want. I would rather want to have option to choose which device I want to connect. So I decide to move that line to other listener but I am not sure which I should use, because first option was "onClick" but it doesn't work with Spinner so I was trying with "onTouch" but also does not work like I want, please could you show me direction how I should implement it?

Comment: Set OnItemSelectedListener after you set items to the adapter

Comment: Add one dummy item. like... `Select Device` and make a condition to adapter that if select device option is selected.. do nothing.